# Trying to use "Monthpicker" Jquery UI widget and bind a change

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I am using http://lucianocosta.info/jquery.mtz.monthpicker/ to display a "calendar" that only displays month and year.

My Javascript to initialize this is

```
var Year = new Date().getFullYear();
var Month = new Date().getMonth() + 1;
$(document).ready(function() {

     $('#monthpicker_widget').monthpicker({
        startYear: 2011,
        finalYear: new Date().getFullYear()
    });

     $('#monthpicker_widget').bind('onchange',function(e){
        alert("input change");
     });
});
```

In my HTML I have this

```
 <p> Date: <input id="monthpicker_widget" class="mtz-monthpicker-widgetcontainer" type="text"> </p>
```

Here is what I want...

I want the input field to show current month/year right off the bat. So when the page loads I want 11/2012 in it. When the user clicks on the input field, it will pop up with the MonthPicker widget (which it currently is). When the user selects a different year or month, I want the input field to update -- it is currently doing this. Although if I refresh the page, it doesn't revert back to CURRENT date.

What I want to do is use the month and year data when the user changes it. I am using it in a table to display different data depending on the month / year. The bind method I have above is not displaying the alert when the input is changed.

Any suggestions on resolving this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since clicking a month is the only way to update the text box (changing the year and clicking out of the box closes it but does not update the text, I'd consider this a bug!), you can handle the `monthpicker-click-month` event as shown in the [documentation](http://lucianocosta.info/jquery.mtz.monthpicker/):

```
$('#events_widget').monthpicker().bind('monthpicker-click-month', function (e, month) {
    alert('You clicked on month ' + month);
});
```

As a side note, I would consider using the standard [jQuery UI Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) and customize it to your liking, as it is much more supported and doesn't have the above mentioned bug.